# Expand Div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I like to do something terribly simple

Had a div that show only a little bit of image
click on div, expand to the image height
reclick on it, contract to to original height

Now, my test is not concluant ! so many problems !, is there a simpler method around ?

[link on some funny result !](http://ldetek.com/test1.php)

mostly as [this](http://be.twixt.us/jquery/codeExpander.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is to have a handle, which toggles a panel:

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="handle">Click Me</div>
  <div class="panel">
    <img src="bigImage.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

And then something like:

```
$(".handle").click(function(){
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Not only is this simple, but it's predictable, and won't leave the user confused about the behavior.

Comment: i come to the same solution..... because the image disapear... so handle it's the way i will go !

Comment: do i really have to wrap everything in a block div ?

Comment: @marc-andre menard: You could also animate the height. I've setup an example here: http://jsbin.com/ajoyi3/edit